# Ubuntu bind9 doesn't resolve local domain

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I installed bind9 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

But I've problems with resolving local domains. Extern like google.com works fine.

Here are my configuraton files and troubleshoots i've made.

Forward:

```
$TTL 2D
@       IN      SOA     ns.mancina.home. root.mancina.home. (
                        22      ; Serial
                                8H      ; Refresh
                                2H      ; Retry
                                4W      ; Expire
                                3H )
@       IN      NS      ns.mancina.home.
        IN      A       192.168.1.150

ns      IN      A       192.168.1.150
lenny   IN      A       192.168.1.150
homer   IN      A       192.168.1.110
```

Reverse:

```
    $TTL 2D
@       IN      SOA     ns.mancina.home. root.mancina.home. (
                        2      ; Serial
                                8H      ; Refresh
                                2H      ; Retry
                                4W      ; Expire
                                3H )

@       IN      NS      ns.mancina.home.
150     IN      PTR     lenny.mancina.home.
110     IN      PTR     homer.mancina.home.
```

named.conf.local

```
root@lenny:/etc/bind# cat named.conf.local 
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
logging {
    channel query.log {      
        file "/var/log/query.log"; 
        severity info;
    print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
        print-category yes; 
    }; 
    category queries { query.log; }; 
};
```

named.local.conf

```
zone "mancina.home" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.mancina.home";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.1.168.192";
};
```

named.conf.options

```
root@lenny:/etc/bind# cat named.conf.options 
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
     forwarders {
         8.8.8.8    ;
     };
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Tests

```
root@lenny:/etc/bind# named-checkzone db.mancina.home ./db.mancina.home 
zone db.mancina.home/IN: loaded serial 22
OK

dig lenny.mancina.home

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> lenny.mancina.home
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 17304
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lenny.mancina.home.        IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           10610   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2017071400 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.150#53(192.168.1.150)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 14 18:01:46 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 122




nslookup lenny.mancina.home
Server:     192.168.1.150
Address:    192.168.1.150#53

** server can't find lenny.mancina.home: NXDOMAIN
root@lenny:~# nslookup google.com
Server:     192.168.1.150
Address:    192.168.1.150#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.205.142
```

I hope anyone can see an error in the conf or give me an advice what could be wrong.

TIA
Mattia

Comment: output of `named-checkconf -z` would also be useful.

Comment: lol, what's the output of `named.conf`  did you include all your config files?

Comment: include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";   
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";   
′nclude "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

Comment: right,  missing you zone config because that file isn't even included

Comment: you could/should merge `named.local.conf` into `named.conf.local`

what "Documentation" says to generate a conf that isn't referenced ?

Comment: ok, no I just misunderstood something. It works now. I really thank you Jacob. have a nice week-end ;)

Answer (score 1):

named.local.conf not included in named.conf

add this line to `named.conf`:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.local.conf";
```

Comment: home is not a TLD.

Comment: its a local domain so i don't think that this is the problem

Comment: the problem is you need to hijack your upstream dns servers with the bind server OR register the domain name and point your NS records to this server, which may not work for you if you use private ip ranges.

Comment: just because you're running bind doesn't mean your sever OS is configured to look up dns from that bind server, it's very common to have bind as a service run on server that does not use the entries stored in dns for resolution.  The same can be said for  HTTP, if you configured a virtual host as "google.com" that does mean that the server is going to hit the vhost when you curl google.com.

update your DNS configuration so the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` is `nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver ::1`

Comment: whats the difference between the loopback address and the ip-address of the dns(192.168.1.150)?

Comment: and i changed the name-server to the loopback address on /etc/network/interfaces and this made no difference. The error is the same